# a question on Cauchy's integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I know from calculus that, if $C$ is closed path in the complex plane and $a$ a point inside $C$, then

$\int_C \frac{dz}{z-a}=2\pi i$

What happens if $a$ is not inside. Is it true that $\int_C \frac{dz}{z-a}=0$ in that case? How does one prove it?

Thanks friends

Answer (score 2):

Recall that
$$\oint_C f(z)dz = 0$$ if $f(z)$ is analytic inside $C$.

Is $\dfrac1{z-a}$ analytic inside $C$, if $a$ lies outside $C$?